# Parsing deserialized Json data Fails - c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I have this [json data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/user/createorupdate) to parse but I get parsing error, can some please shed some light?

This is the Json data I'd like to parse when received:

```
{
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx",
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users",
      "name": "bbbbb",
      "properties": {
        "firstName": "aaaa",
        "lastName": "cccc",
        "email": "someone@somewhere.xyz",
        "state": "active",
        "registrationDate": "somedate",
        "note": null,
        "groups": [],
        "identities": [
          {
            "provider": "Basic",
            "id": "someone@somewhere.xyz"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

These are the classes I've created to deserialize data into:

```
 public class NewUserAPIMResultingData
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string id { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("type")]
            public string thisType { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string name { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("properties")]
            public NewUserAPIMResultingDataProperties properties { get; set; }
        }
        public class NewUserAPIMResultingDataProperties
        {
            [JsonProperty("firstName")]
            public string userFirstName { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("lastName")]
            public string userLastName { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("email")]
            public string userEmail { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("state")]
            public string state { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("registrationDate")]
            public string registrationDate { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("note")]
            public string note { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("groups")]
            public IEnumerable<string> groups { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("identities")]
            public IEnumerable<NewUserAPIMResultingDataPropertyIdentity> identities { get; set; }
        }
        public class NewUserAPIMResultingDataPropertyIdentity
        {
            [JsonProperty("provider")]
            public string provider { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
```

This is the .NET c# code i'm using to read received and parsed json data:

var formCreateUserContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var newUserResult = new NewUserAPIMResultingData();

```
            using (HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client2.PutAsync(url, formCreateUserContent))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        var stringContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        newUserResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewUserAPIMResultingData>(stringContent);
                    }
                    foreach (var z in newUserResult.properties.identities)
                        Console.WriteLine(z);
                }
            }
```

This is the error I get on console: [09/06/2020 13:34:13] Executed 'TestCreateAPIMUser' 
[09/06/2020 13:34:13] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: TestCreateAPIMUser. Newtonsoft.Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'properties.groups', line 13, position 7.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: i've updated the answer with the parsing error

Comment: Can you make this change and try `public object note { get; set; }
        public IList<object> groups { get; set; }`

Comment: try to change groups property to dynamic or JObject or object for debug purposes and look what's inside

Comment: I can't reproduce it, there is no errors with the given JSON

Comment: tried to change public IList<string> groups { get; set; } but same parsing error

Comment: change it to object from string

Comment: ok yes, sorry, this worked public IList<object> groups { get; set; } thanks a bunch @viveknuna and everyone for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the declaration for the below properties. Because `note` and `groups`can be groups can be other object then `string` and `IList<string>`

```
public object note { get; set; }        
public IList<object> groups { get; set; }
```

Comment: changing note was not necessary

Comment: Yes I agree, but it can be other than string based on the json provided

Answer (score 1):

Possibly an issue with the encoding of the source json?  You can verify that your C# class definitions are OK using the following test code...

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        const string json = @"{
          ""id"": ""/subscriptions/xxxx"",
          ""type"": ""Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users"",
          ""name"": ""bbbbb"",
          ""properties"": {
            ""firstName"": ""aaaa"",
            ""lastName"": ""cccc"",
            ""email"": ""someone@somewhere.xyz"",
            ""state"": ""active"",
            ""registrationDate"": ""somedate"",
            ""note"": null,
            ""groups"": [],
            ""identities"": [
              {
                ""provider"": ""Basic"",
                ""id"": ""someone@somewhere.xyz""
              }
            ]
          }
        }";

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewUserAPIMResultingData>(json);

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.properties.identities.Count() == 1);
    }
```

I copied the classes and the tests passed, the only difference is that I pasted the json as a constant so Visual Studio automatically encoded it correctly.

Comment: thank you for your help, it seems the problem lied with what was boxed inside "groups" I was assigning it to string enumerable but using object instead solved it as per above answer